# How to store repeating rows of data (json) in a single sql record

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

Working with a Postgres and prisma database, creating a table called cast list, which would include a list of actors and roles and some other data at creation of list. Trying to find the best way to store this. Shape would be

Createdby, project, comment, shared_with, [{talentId, role, comment}]

The input form will allow a person to add as many rows as needed to add talents to a cast list. The talent is a table in the database.

Basically, a person will create a list, add a comment and select multiple talents to be saved in the list, but not just a talent id, each talent selection needs an extra two pieces of information like role and comment.

Thinking this is a json block stored in an array in a field of one row/record but was wondering if this is common or best practice.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have described, you are looking to create a many-to-many hook table.

So you have a `cast` table, a `talent` table and then you need a `cast_talent` table. This will allow you to relate talent to cast entries with associated comments. A table structure like so could work:

```
cast:
createdby,
project,
comment,
shared_with

talent:
id
...

cast_talent:
talent_id (fk to talent table)
cast_id (fk to cast table)
role
comment
```

I'm not sure what other relations you have in your data, but this will allow you to store unique references between talent and cast without relying on a json record of arrays in a row in the cast table. Although that is possible with the jsonb data type in postgres, but not as efficient for querying in different ways (for example finding all cast entries belonging to x talent).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Was thinking about this. I don’t have a cast table because it’s a data record that happens before an actual cast. It’s a prospective suggestion. Cast might be an actual table in the future but it would be the actual cast of a show. This record is for suggesting talents to a director or casting manager.

Comment: Ok so in your original question you state that you’re creating a table called cast list? What data exists that you’re going to reference against? If the suggestions are against a record from elsewhere it might be that you need to make your hook table only have 1 foreign key for talent_id and then another column called reference which you use to link to your external data source. Then load them up from there - essentially a many-to-one relation